# Unable to display the top of the page using anuglar Router

Tags: angular, angular-routing

here my issue is when ever i am routing to next page or another page using angular router then it is displaying the bottom of the page first  and it is not displaying the top the page :

below is my template page code after clicking this it will be going to next page but in the next page it is displaying bottom of the page

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user']">
  link to user component
</a>
```

Comment: For how much time it is showing only bottom?
Can you also put both html templates' code? @Devpop

Comment: @Debojyoti not for how much time . when ever i click  anchor tag it is redirecting to the page but it is showing bottom level of the page first instead top and  i can't put the code right now

Comment: Is there any error in console log?
Also if you navigate that link manually by putting the path in browser's address bar, is it showing the same thing?

Comment: @Devpop. Add this to your ngOnInit(): window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

If your are in Angular v6.1+, you can can fix the position at top in your `app-routing.module.ts` :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```